# Inequality on random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Can anyone give me a reference on a proof of the following result?

Let $X, Y$ be random variables with values in $\{x_1, \cdots, x_n, \cdots \}$. Then $\sum_{i} |\mathbb{P}(X = x_i) - \mathbb{P}(Y = x_i)| \leqslant 2 \mathbb{P}(X \neq Y)$.

Comment: is it $∑_i |P(X=x_i )−P(Y=x_i )|≤2P(X≠Y)$??

Comment: Yes, thanks; I edited it

Comment: User posts answer 6 months after question is asked and OP accepts it 2 minutes later? This does not smell good. "Fortunately", so to speak, the accepted answer does not answer the question.

Comment: The formerly accepted answer is now unaccepted and deleted. The newly accepted answer (not upvoted by the OP) provides a very short hint, so short that one wonders that the OP is able to build a full proof from it. Sorry but this still does not smell good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: express both sides in terms of $p_{ij} = P(X=x_i, Y=x_j)$.